# Save, Validate, Publish URL's not being called in JourneyBuilder Platform V1 Custom Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I'm having trouble getting ExactTarget's JourneyBuilder to call my Custom Activities Save, Publish or Validate URLs.

I've gotten past the undocumented item in their framework where you have to add a "isConfigured" = true key to the metaData you pass back via PostMonger, which enables me to actually attempt to activate my Interaction (by clicking the "Activate" button), but the Activate never succeeds and instead I get a bunch of errors. Specifically w/ Error Code 121017.

Watching my server logs, it seems that JourneyBuilder's activation backend never calls my Save/Validate/Publish endpoints.

Here is what my configurationArguments looks like ( and i've tried many iterations )

```
"configurationArguments": {
    "applicationExtensionKey": "my-key",
    "save": {
        "url": "https://mydomain.com/journeybuilder/api/v1/save",
        "body": "Hello",
        "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": true
    },
    "publish": {
        "url": "https://mydomain.com/journeybuilder/api/v1/publish",
        "verb": "POST",
        "body": "Hello",
        "useJwt": true
    },
    "validate": {
        "url": "https://mydomain.com/journeybuilder/api/v1/validate",
        "verb": "POST",
        "body": "Hello",
        "useJwt": true
    }
},
```

Any suggestions on how to get my Custom Activity to activate in JourneyBuilder?

Comment: Hi Andy, please reach out to me at jbdev@exacttarget.com.  I will need some information from you to be able to properly debug this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem and am posting the answer here for others.

**The "body" key can only accept valid JSON or an empty value. Anything else will cause the JourneyBuilder system to explode.**

All of the following examples work:

```
"configurationArguments": {
    "applicationExtensionKey": "my-key",
    "save": {
        "url": "https://mydomain.com/journeybuilder/api/v1/save",
        "body": "{'foo':'bar'}", 
        "verb": "POST",
        "useJwt": true
    },
    "publish": {
        "url": "https://mydomain.com/journeybuilder/api/v1/publish",
        "verb": "POST",
        "body": "",
        "useJwt": true
    },
    "validate": {
        "url": "https://mydomain.com/journeybuilder/api/v1/validate",
        "verb": "POST",
        "body": "{}",
        "useJwt": true
    }
},
```

This value restriction is not currently documented, but is just what I'm able to determine using trial and error.

Comment: Apparently this is a bug in the V1 Platform an the "body" key should accept any type of string value. ExactTarget has communicated to me that they are working on a fix, but until then I'll leave this answer in place as it immediately solves the issue.